# jquery animate() called on 2 elements only works on one?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Just wondering if anyone had any insight into why this might be happening. 
I have a map on my website that scrolls when you move the mouse to the borders of the container its in. It also highlights a specific city when you hover over it, which is accomplished by creating a map overlay with the same dimensions as the original map. Therefore I just apply the same left and top CSS to get the two images to move in unison. Example here: http://www.bestattorney.com/locations/

My problem is that when you hover on the links below the map, the area that you're hovering on is supposed to come to the center of the screen. It works but I would like to add a little bit of animation so that the move isn't so jarring. When I change the animate({}) from 0 to 1000, the result is that only the overlay image moves, like so: http://www.bestattorney.com/locations/locations2.html

I was wondering if there was any reason that anyone could think of off the top of their heads as to why this happens? It would be great if both images moved together like the do in the first example.

What I suspect it to be is that there's a setInterval(100) which runs the animate function, which would mean that there would be 10 animates() running by the time the first animation finishes. I'm not quite sure if there's anything to be done about that so hopefully someone could provide some insight! Thanks All!

(Scrolling plugin by Mjfisheruk: https://github.com/mjfisheruk/jquery.pan)
Simplified code for reference or you can just look in the source. 
Please let me know if I can answer any questions, thanks.

```js
var interval; //creates the setInterval object

$("#container").pan({
  //Initialize scrolling by placing mouse cursor at the edge of map. 
});

var pan = function(areaX,areaY){
   var onInterval = function() {
        //If the mouse is on the edge of the map
        //check which way the mouse is moving
        //set varX and varY to the location they  should be at
     
         if (areaX != "" & areaY != "") {
             varX = areaX;
             varY = areaY;
           }
      
         $("#container img").animate({
                left: varX + "px",
                top: varY + "px"
         }, 0);
   }
   interval = setInterval(onInterval,100);
}

$("li").mouseenter(function() {
      //find out the coordinates of the hovered area and enter those values in areaX and areaY
      clearInterval(interval)
      $("#container").pan({
          //Initialize scrolling, but this time use hovered area to decide where to scroll to. 
       },areaX, areaY);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <map>
    <area>
    <area>
    <area>
  </map>
  <img id="map-overlay">
  <img id="background-map">
  
</div>
    
<ul>
  <li>Location1</li>
  <li>Location2</li>
  <li>Location3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your animations may be stacking up on top of each other. Since you are calling the animate function inside an interval that is shorter than the length of the animation, all of the animations get queued up. Since the interval calls animate every time it runs, there are a lot of 1 second animations that get queued that don't actually animate anything because they are all moving to the same place.

I think you should be able to solve your issue if you do the following:

- Only call the `animate` function when you are animating to a new location
- Before you call `animate` call the `stop` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)), this will clear the queue and make your new animation start immediately

I tested adding the stop call on your demo page and it made the animations act a little weird, but they eventually made it to where they were supposed to be as opposed to stopping part way and not lining up the two maps. I think reducing the number of times you call `animate` will fix the weirdness.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up getting it to work by clearing the interval if I'm hovering on the navigation links and resetting it if I'm hovering over the map. I had to call stop(true,true) on the animation when I would have preferred to use stop(true,false) so that it doesn't jump to the end of the animation but for some reason that still gives me the same problem I had before. I'm ok enough with it to leave it though. Thanks again!